# Find IDs from a list that don't exist in a table

Tags: postgresql, if-not-exists

Say I have the following schema and data:

```
create table images(
  id int not null
);

insert into images values(1), (2), (3), (4), (6), (8);
```

I want to perform a query like:

```
select id from images where id not exists in(4, 5, 6);
```

But this doesn't work. The case above should return `5`, since it doesn't exist in the table records.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use an outer join against a `values` list (similar to Martin's answer mentioned above):

```
select t.id
from (
  values (4),(5),(6) 
) as t(id)
  left join images i on i.id = t.id
where i.id is null;
```

or a `not exists` together with the row constructor:

```
select *
from ( 
   values (4),(5),(6)
) as v(id)
where not exists (select *
                  from images i
                  where i.id = v.id);
```

If you like you can also put the `values` clause into a CTE to make the final query easier to read:

```
with v (id) as (
 values (4),(5),(6)
)
select v.id
from v
  left join images i on i.id = v.id
where i.id is null;
```

Comment: Very good answer.  To me, for a large list, all the () around the values -- e.g. (4) --  make it less clear.  I do know how to edit them in fast, and they do seem to be REQUIRED.

Comment: Good answer indeed. But in mysql version > 8.0 we should use VALUES with ROW constructor: values (4),(5),(6) -> values row(4),row(5),row(6). 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html#:~:text=VALUES%20is%20a%20DML%20statement,as%20a%20standalone%20SQL%20statement.

Answer (score 21):

One way of doing it would be to use [`VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-values.html) to create a table expression with the ids to check and [`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html) to find the missing ones.

```
SELECT id
FROM (VALUES(4),(5),(6)) V(id)
EXCEPT
SELECT id 
FROM images;
```

Answer (score 17):

While using `EXCEPT` like [@Martin provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141132/3684), remember to make it `EXCEPT`**`ALL`**, unless you want to pay a little extra for trying to fold duplicates.

BTW, a `VALUES` expression can stand on its own:

```
VALUES (4),(5),(6)
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT id FROM images;
```

But you get default column names this way.

For a *long list* of values it may be more convenient to provide it as array and unnest. Shorter syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest('{4,5,6}'::int[]) id
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT id FROM images;
```

There are a couple of basic techniques for the task:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a second table and join them.

```
create table images1(
  id int not null
);

create table images2(
  id int not null
);

insert into images1 values(1), (2), (3), (4), (6), (8);

insert into images2 values (4), (5), (6);

SELECT i2.ID

FROM images2 i2

LEFT JOIN images1 i1
    ON i1.ID = i2.ID

WHERE i1.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: If you're executing a simple select and you're creating a table just for this it may not be the best solution.